# implementation of dependency injection like angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have recently an interview and the interviewer simply ask me one question and he say me take your time the question is "can you implement dependency injection like angular good program?" i try to do my best but it seem the interview don't like my program so can anyone give me a simple advice how can i implement it like angular?
Thanks

Comment: You need to ask a better question, including code examples and the errors and a whole lot more information.

Comment: Was the interviewer asking how to implement dependency injection in general, or a dependency injection system like Angular uses? A better question would be why is an interviewer asking you to code up a dependency injection container when so many of them exist?

Comment: he not asked me the implementation in general he want simple injection implementation like angular ? i know for sure it is a weird question

Answer (score 0):

```
var WelcomeController = function (Greeter) {
    document.write(Greeter.greet());
};

var Injector = {

    dependencies: {},

    process: function(target) {
        var FN_ARGS = /^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m;
        var FN_ARG_SPLIT = /,/;
        var FN_ARG = /^\s*(_?)(\S+?)\1\s*$/;
        var STRIP_COMMENTS = /((\/\/.*$)|(\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/))/mg;
        var text = target.toString();
        var args = text.match(FN_ARGS)[1].split(',');

        target.apply(target, this.getDependencies(args));
    },

    getDependencies: function(arr) {
        var self = this;
        return arr.map(function(value) {

            return self.dependencies[value];
        });            
    },

    register: function(name, dependency) {
        this.dependencies[name] = dependency;
    }

};

var RobotGreeter = {
  greet: function() {
    return 'Domo Arigato';
  }
};

var OtherGreeter = {
    greet: function() {
      return 'That will do pig.';
    }
};

// Randomly register a different greeter to show that WelcomeController is truly dynamic.
Injector.register('Greeter', Math.random() > 0.5 ? RobotGreeter : OtherGreeter);

Injector.process(WelcomeController);
```